# Get the latest version of every row in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, inner-join

I need to grab the latest version of every row to not get duplicate data. "_sdc_sequence" is a unix epoch attached to the record during replication and determine the order of all the versions of a row.
I would like to get cost and impressions fro each campaign everyday

I have tried to use INNER JOIN but I could not get the data. when I tried to use "account" and "clientname" for attribute (every row has the same clientname and account) I got cero in cost and impressions. Maybe the attributes are wrongs

```
SELECT DISTINCT day, cost, impressions, campaign  
FROM `adxxxxx_xxxxxxxx` account 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
     MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq,
     campaignid
   FROM `adxxxxx_xxxxxxxx`
   GROUP BY campaignid) clientname 
ON account.campaignid = clientname.campaignid 
AND account._sdc_sequence = clientname.seq
ORDER by day
```

There is another way to do this? or How I can fix it?
thank you

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It is not even clear where the `select` columns are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT row.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY _sdc_sequence DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row 
  FROM `adxxxxx_xxxxxxxx` t
  GROUP BY campaignid
)
```

Comment: i have answered your question - `There is another way to do this?`. If you have another one - please post as a new one and i (or someone else) will be happy to answer/help